# Есть ли такой же плагин для Brackets как в notepad?

Tags: html, css, плагин, notepad++, brackets

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет!
В ноутпаде было так:

Допустим ты написал уже дофигище кода и следующий раз когда ты хочешь написать, допустим класс "myClass", то когда ты только начинаешь писать "mY" ноутпад сразу предлагает тебе уже существующие в документе классы с похожим наименованием - "myClass".

Есть ли такое для брэкетс?

PS: сам не нашел

Answer (score 0):

http://brackets.dnbard.com/extension/growlscript.brackets.classcompletion

Попробуйте установить этот плагин на brackets.